# How to save tshark statistics in variables

Tags: python, wireshark, tshark

I would like to save the output of a `tshark` command in a variable.

For example if I run:

```
tshark -r capture.pcap -qz io,stat,0
```

I will get :

```
Time            |frames|  bytes

00.000-060.000     742     51660
```

I want to save the total number of frames in a variable in my script for further calculations.

Answer (score 1):

On my system `tshark`'s output format differs from the one you've shown in the question.
To make parsing more robust, I've changed the command-line:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import shlex
from itertools import dropwhile
from subprocess import check_output as qx

# get tshark output
command = "tshark -r capture.pcap -qz 'io,stat,0,COUNT(frame)frame'"
lines = qx(shlex.split(command)).splitlines()

# parse output
lines = dropwhile(lambda line: not line.rstrip().endswith("COUNT"), lines)
next(lines) # skip header
frames_count = int(next(lines).split()[1])
print(frames_count)
```

You don't need to call `tshark` to get statistics from a pcap file. You could use a Python library that can parse pcap files e.g., using [`scapy`](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/usage.html#reading-pcap-files):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from scapy.all import rdpcap

a = rdpcap('capture.pcap')
frames_count = len(a)
print(frames_count)
```

To get count for `tshark -r capture.pcap -qz 'io,stat,0,ip.src==192.168.230.146'` command using `scapy`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from scapy.all import IP, sniff

a = sniff(offline='capture.pcap',
          lfilter=lambda p: IP in p and p[IP].src == '192.168.230.146')
count = len(a)
print(count)
```

Comment: I think the first solution is better in a way that I want to find out the number of received packet from each source. So the command will be: "tshark -r capture.pcap -qz 'io,stat,0,ip.src==192.168.230.146". In this case I need to parse the output as you did. Is scapy able to filter based on src or dst?

Comment: yes. `count = len(a.filter(lambda pkt: pkt['IP'].src == '192.168.230.146'))`

Comment: @samaneh: you could combine both loading and filtering: `count = len(sniff(offline='capture.pcap', lfilter=lambda p: p[IP].src == '192.168.230.146'))`, add `from scapy.all import IP, sniff` before it.

Answer (score 0):

First save the output to a file :

Either by running this command in shell:

`tshark -r capture.pcap -qz io,stat,0 > abc.txt`:

Or use `subprocess.Popen()`:

```
from subprocess import Popen

with open("abc.txt","w") as f:
    Popen(["tshark" ,"-r","capture.pcap","-qz", "io,stat,0"],stdout=f)
```

Now open the file and calculate the total number of frames:

```
with open("abc.txt") as f:
    next(f)  #skip header
    tot_frames=sum(int(line.split()[1]) for line in f if line.strip()) 
    print (tot_frames)         #prints 742
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is old, but the concept lives on.  Another way to get the packet count is with `capinfos`, which included with most wireshark/tshark installations.

```
pcap_file=trace.pcap
packet_count=$(capinfos -Mc "$pcap_file" 2>/dev/null | awk '/^Number of packets/ {print $NF}')
```